# jQuery Date Picker Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [jQuery's Pretty Event Calendar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Pretty-Event-Calendar-&-Datepicker-Plugin-For-jQuery-Calendar-js.html). For some reason it is extremely encypted looking on my website, so I went ahead and just isolated the plugin on a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZGbPO) and you can see the same exact issues. I followed their simple directions to a tea..

Anyone know of this issue?

I am just using the html input:

```
<input type="text" id="dt" placeholder="date picker">
<div id="dd"></div>
```

And the trigger:

```
$('#dd').calendar({
  trigger: '#dt',
});
```

Comment: Do you actually import the javascript module?

Comment: The original js file in the plugin demo contains Chinese characters. The problem that those characters in the js in your codepen (which I assume is the same as in your calendar.js) have somehow been converted to disallowed symbols. If your downloaded file was like that, download it again. If your downloaded file is fine but its corrupt on the server, then its possible that the encoding was incorrect for your ftp upload or that your server doesn't support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You didn't apply 5th step from the [tutorial](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Pretty-Event-Calendar-&-Datepicker-Plugin-For-jQuery-Calendar-js.html). You see weird chars because it's printing Chinese days and months as they have to be replaced with English ones.
2. Some default styles in chrome (and possibly other browsers) are messing with the layout of the calendar. To make it readable I had to add one style to the CSS file:

CSS:

```
ol, ul{list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px; }
```

Other than that, I think it works fine now.

**DEMO**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXLLxe